# Proof: a group action on a $T_2$ space that is free and wandering is properly discontinuous

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

An exercise that was left in class asked to prove that a free and wandering group action $G$ on $T_2$ and locally compact space $X$ is properly discontinuous. My solution to this problem seems to not use the fact that $X$ is locally compact. My proof is that given any $x$ in $X$ since the action is wandering there exist some open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that ($U$|$U$) is finite. Then for each $g$ in ($U\mid U$) that is not the identity and using the fact that $X$ is $T_2$ and since $gx$ is not equal to $x$ since the group action is free I can create two disjoint open sets $U_g$ and $V_g$ that separate $x$ and $gx$. Since G is a group action we have that $g$ is a continuous function so $g^{-1}(V_g)$ is also open for each $g$. Taking the finite intersection of $U$ and all $U_g$ and all $g^{-1}(V_g)$ I can create an open neighborhood $A$ of $x$ such that for any non identity element $g$ in $G$ $A$ intersected with $g(A)$ is empty so it's properly discontinuous. What's the error in this proof or is the locally compact condition not necessary? Also is it implicit that the group action on a topological space is continuous?

Comment: What does $(U \mid U)$ mean?

Comment: @Paul Frost Sorry the set ($U$|$U$) is the transporter of $U$ or the subset of elements of $G$ such that $gU$ is not disjoint with $U$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your proof is correct. The point is the *definition* of a properly discontinuous action. Your understanding seems to be the standard, but in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action_(mathematics) you find another definition:

> An action is properly discontinuous if $X$ is a locally compact space and for every compact subset $K ⊂ X$ the set $\{ g ∈ G : g K ∩ K ≠ ∅ \}$ is finite.